# HTML Input (type=image) not working on Firefox 4

Tags: html, input

```
<input  type="image"value="Delete" title="Delete" name="cmd_delete" src="bin/images/common/delete.png"/>
```

The above HTML code is for a Delete button in my application. The problem is that this button does not work in Firefox 4 but works in other browsers. Please how can I fix this.

Comment: What exactly does not work? What value is received on server side?

Comment: You'll need to give a better description of what doesn't work. See http://jsfiddle.net/f672W/

Comment: @What does not work is the server side code. I have a php function that checks whether the value of the image field is set and then does something. That is what does not work

Comment: @yankitwizzy - Can you provide the entire form markup?

Comment: @Jared Farrish
http://pastie.org/2091653

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `<button name="cmd_delete" value=""><img src=".."/></button>` instead of input.

Answer (score 11):

You're basically abusing the `<input type="image">` to have a button with a background image. The `<input type="image">` represents an image map. The mouse position on the button is been sent as `cmd_delete.x` and `cmd_delete.y` parameters. But you are not interested in the mouse position. Replace it by a normal `<input type="submit">` and use CSS to specify a background image. E.g.

```
<input type="submit" name="cmd_delete" class="delete" value="" />
```

with

```
input.delete {
    background-image: url('bin/images/common/delete.png');
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and check it as follows

```
if (isset($_GET['cmd_delete'])) {
    // Delete button pressed.
}
```

Comment: @yan: that's fine if you don't want to support IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<input type="button" class=”button” value="Delete" title="Delete" name="cmd_delete" />

.button{
      background: url('bin/images/common/delete.png') no-repeat top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works in IE, FF (and IE6, BalusC!):

```
<input type="submit" value="" style="background-image: url('bin/images/common/delete.png');width:262px;height:37px;border:0;cursor: pointer;" />
```

Comment: My IE6-fail comment didn't concern my own answer, but the "last ans" of lonut staicu (which is currently accepted).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose:

`<input type="image" name="submit" src="signout.png" />`

If you are using php, change your code from

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_x']))`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for $_REQUEST['submit_x'] if its set or not empty.
Older browsers don't set $_REQUEST['submit'] when using input type image.
Don't really know why...

Then there's no need to apply CSS to the tag.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with using `<button name="cmd_delete" value=""><img src=".."/></button>` is that you still see the button behind the image. It looks horrible. Why is this negative voted...it is true, I tried it!