# Jsp and html img button can get the value of request.getParameter

Tags: html, jsp

This is my code

```
    <%
   if(request.getParameter("cart") != null)
    {
     ......
     }
    <%

   <form method="post"><input  class="auto-style2"  height="44" name="cart" 
    src="divers/panier.jpg" type="image" width="71" />
```

So when I press the button name="cart"  I can get request.getParameter("cart").

How to know its a post back when I click on the `img` ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? Are you trying to get information about the image? Or just know that an image has been clicked to issue the POST?

Comment: I just want to know that an image has been clicked to issue the POST!!!

Comment: Look at checked answer and BalusC's answer  at  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402380/html-input-type-image-not-working-on-firefox-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How to know its a post back when I click on the img ?*

Check the request method.

```
if ("post".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
    // It's a POST request.
}
```

Or, better, let the form submit to a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and do the job in `doPost()` method.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you're in essence abusing the `<input type="image">` here to have just a button with a background image. It will not sent a request parameter `cart`, but instead send the mouse cursor position on the image as `cart.x` and `cart.y`. You need to check those parameters instead.

```
if (request.getParameter("cart.x") != null) {
    // Image button is clicked.
}
```

See also [HTML Input (type=image) not working on Firefox 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402380/html-input-type-image-not-working-on-firefox-4/6402422#6402422).

Comment: Thank's for your help, your the best!