# Issue submitting form values on post (works in Chrome but not FireFox)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am guessing this is a REALLY SIMPLE issue but since im relatively new to asp.net mvc, i will blame that.  Basically I have the form below, when i submit the values get posted in Chrome, but not FireFox.

> ```
> @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}))
> {
>     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
>
>
> <text>
>     Fill out this form homie
>     <br/><br/>
> </text>
>
>     <input type="image" src="~/assets/img/male.jpg" name="iama" value="male" />
>     @Html.Raw("&nbsp;")
>     @Html.Raw("&nbsp;")
>     <input type="image" src="~/assets/img/female.jpg" name="iama" value="female" />
>
> }
> ```

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [HTML Input (type=image) not working on Firefox 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402380/html-input-type-image-not-working-on-firefox-4)

You defined an Image Map but should use a button

```
 <input  type="submit" name="iama" value="male" style="background: url('assets/img/male.jpg');width: 160px;height:160px;border: 0;" />
```

Comment: Thanks that was it, shame that i can just use the image itself, buttons with background images is much harder to pull off (i mean you have to do specific stying to get it to look like an ... wait for it ... image.